# How to create menu with activity switch?

Tags: android, android-activity, menu

How to create the menu on Android with activities switcher not to redraw it every time using intent? I've tried to use ViewFlipper, but I want to change views programmatically. This is activity class I want to switch to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can make same thing using fragments instead of activity.
Edit: sample code to see full sample visit http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Defining Variables
private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initializing Toolbar and setting it as the actionbar
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Initializing NavigationView
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if(menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
            else menuItem.setChecked(true);

            //Closing drawer on item click
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){


                //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                case R.id.inbox:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inbox Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    InboxFragment inboxFragment = new InboxFragment();
                    addFragment(inboxFragment);
                    return true;

                // For rest of the options we just show a toast on click

                case R.id.starred:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Stared Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    StarredFragment starredFragment = new StarredFragment();
                    addFragment(starredFragment);
                    return true;
    }
        }
    });
```

}

```
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment){
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,fragment); // you can use add but in that case previous fragment is visible so better approach is to use replace
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

}

Comment: Its your answer ?? Then elaborate please .

Comment: what i understand from your question is that you have drop down menu and when u select one option that specific activity will open right ?

Comment: What about used ArrayAdapter for list view inside this xml?

Comment: It's NavigationView, not drop down

Comment: Ok thanks for telling me NavigationView i am not aware of it.

Comment: I was thinking that if you make fragments in one activity and use transaction.add to add new fragment then it will not re create
if we use transaction.replace to add new fragment then it re creates.

Comment: Yeah sure wait i am making it for you.